# Given $\overline{AB}=c$, $\overline{AC}=b$, $m_a$, construct the triangle $ABC$?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

> Given $\overline{AB}=c$, $\overline{AC}=b$, $m_a$, construct the triangle $ABC$.

I did the following:

> [image]

And then used the compass to draw the distances $c,b$:

> [image]

I've drawn the paralelogram:

> [image]

After drawing the line segment BC, we have:

> [image]

Is my construction correct? I've seen other constructions, specially this [one](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/tr1.shtml#abmc) from Cut-the-Knot, but it seemed a little bit more advanced (I know next to nothing in geometric constructions, decided to learn some weeks ago). I'm still afraid that that construction is "better" by having some aspect mine doesn't have.

I spent a bit of time stuck trying to construct this because I thought that "given $b,c,m_a$ meant that these could be any lengths. I figured out later that perhaps, this is impossible (due to basic properties of the triangle: If I fix $b,c$ in a way that it forms a non-degenerate triangle, then $m_a$ is unique). Could you confirm it?

Comment: The statement is a little unclear. What's $m_a$?

Comment: The length of the median from A to BC.

Comment: In your construction, how do you know that $C, m_a$ and $B$ are colinear?

Comment: Good point. I didn't think about that, but I guess I could use the theorem that states that the diagonals of the parallelogram bisect each other.

Comment: You can, but then you must show that $A,B,A',C$ is a parallelogram. The thing to keep in mind about constructions is that you must be able to justify the result with a proof.

Comment: Yes. Did you look at the other construction in the link I suggested?

Comment: What link are you talking about? I don't see it.

Comment: It's in the "one" in "Is my construction correct? I've seen other constructions, specially this one".

Comment: Oh, okay. However, the constructions given there don't seem to include your problem. Another thing to keep in mind is that your construction needs to be as efficient as possible. There's a better way to construct this triangle than the one you've given.

Comment: Yes. I noticed that it would need further steps. The trouble is that I don't quite understand the construction in there nor the construction in the book i'm reading. I'll try to prove the additional properties in my own construction and see what happens. Wish me luck!

Comment: It would be better for you to try and understand the construction given in the text. If you're having trouble, post your questions.